# Is it possible to transmit video signal on 433MHz?

Tags: rf, communication, video, 433mhz

I'd like to transmit a video of 2MP per frame or less at a distance of 2-3Km.

Is it possible to transmit it on the 433MHz ISM band?

Comment: Hm, lets see, oh there are commercial products available that do this, hm, still hard to answer if it is possible...

Comment: Kindly provide some link of the available product. I searched a lot, but, unable to find any of them.

Comment: Check the bandwidth of your chosen 433MHz TX/RX link against your image resolution. That will let you calculate the frame rate you can achieve from that TX/RX.

Comment: You could use high directivity antennas (Yagi or so). That would provide higher distance with lower power. That would also make your signal harder to detect (for external observer). Compared to other radiation patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems the most likely source to start with: -

[image]

The maximum power is limited to 1 mW (0 dBm) but you can use the full 1.74 MHz bandwidth for video (but no voice unfortunately). So, what will be the link loss at 433.92 MHz and 3 km?

Loss (dB) = 32.45 + 20\$log_{10}\$(f) + 20\$log_{10}\$(d) (Friis equation for free space)

Where f is in MHz and d is in kilometres. This equation tells you how many dB of loss you can expect at a given distance with a given carrier frequency. Plugging in the numbers gives loss = 32.45 dB + 52.7 dB + 9.5 dB = 94.7 dB.

How much signal power will be needed by your radio receiver designed to have a band width of 1.74 MHz: -

The generally accepted formula for ambient temperatures is: -

Receive power = -154 dBm + 10\$log_{10}\$(data rate) and you can substitute data rate with 2 x 1.74 MHz. This means the receiver needs a power of: -

-154 dBm + 65 dBm = 89 dBm. Given that the maximum transmit power is 0 dBm and the link loss is 94.7 dB then there is a significant shortfall. You have to remember that to counter "fades" due to the toplogy of the earth, RF guys tend to want a clearance of 20 to 30 dB. It looks like you have a 6 dB shortfall which can be reduced to a 2 dB shortfall with quarter wave monopoles but you are still a long way off.

Maybe try a slower scan speed for the video - if you can cut down the data rate to 100 kbps the required signal level at the receiver is going to be -154 dBm + 50 dBm = -104 dBm but this still looks a little shy of being a decent link. 10 kbps gives a receiver power of -114 dBm and this looks do-able.

So, in summary, don't expect full blown HD video - it's more like what radio hams used to call slow-scan.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's very possible, but you need an amateur radio license in order to operate at a power level sufficient to do it. The [70-cm ham band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/70-centimeter_band) covers up to 420-450 MHz, depending on jurisdiction.